# Getting undefined reference error while making OPT build but not in debug build

Tags: c++, socket.io, c++14, linker-errors

Can any one explain the following error I get while linking with a prebuilt static libary libsioclient.a.
The linking works fine in case of debug build (OPT=0) but fails in OPT=1

```
*./src/socketio/libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o): In function `sio::socket:
:impl::emit(std::string const&, sio::message::list const&, 
std::function<void (sio::message::list const&)> const&)':
sio_socket.cpp:(.text+0x2822): undefined reference to `vtable for 
std::_Sp_counted_ptr<sio::string_message*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>'
./src/socketio/libsioclient.a(sio_packet.cpp.o): In function 
`sio::from_json(rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, 
rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> > const&, 
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string const>, 
std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<std::string const> > > const&)':
sio_packet.cpp:(.text+0x2e34): undefined reference to `vtable for 
std::_Sp_counted_ptr<sio::string_message*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>'
sio_packet.cpp:(.text+0x3300): undefined reference to `vtable for 
std::_Sp_counted_ptr<sio::object_message*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status*
```

The classes mentioned here i.e. string_message and object_message both derive from the same virtual class message.
While there are many other classes which derive from message, the linker gives error only for these two. Or may be other errors will come down the line when this error gets fixed.

Any clue as to how to triage this linker error would be great help.

Comment: Are you responsible for the static library? Can we see some code about the undefined references? This particular problem can often arise when templates are defined in .cpp files instead of headers.

Comment: libsioclient.a was obtained by building the opensource https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp

The file on which it is giving error is here
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/src/sio_socket.cpp

Comment: While we might be able to figure out a solution here, this is probably more productively posted on _their_ [issues page.](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/issues)

Comment: Thanks. I created the issue there
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/issues/193

Comment: The problem was -flto cxx flag that I was using for OPT build in my makefile. 
Linking worked fine on removing this flag and just keeping -O3 as cxx flat for OPT build